# transform rows and column without using pandas

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a dataframe with only two columns in it.
I am trying to convert the values of one column to headers and the other column to its values.
tried using pivot and all but it is not working.

```
df_pivot_test = sc.parallelize([('a',1), ('b',1), ('c',2), ('d',2), ('e',10)]).toDF(["id","score"])

id  score
a   1
b   1
c   3
d   6
e   10
```

trying to convert this into

```
a   b   c   d   e
1   1   3   6   10
```

any thoughts on how we can do this?
I don't want to use .toPandas() we can achieve it by converting into pandas dataframe. but we have billions of rows because of which we will run into memory issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can do **`pivot and groupBy`** to get your desired result.

**`Try with this method:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

# with literal value in groupby clause

df_pivot_test.groupBy(lit(1)).pivot("id").agg(expr("first(score)")).drop("1").show()
```

**`(or)`**

```
# without any column in groupby clause
df_pivot_test.groupBy().pivot("id").agg(expr("first(score)")).show()
```

**`Result:`**

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|  e|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  1|  2|  2| 10|
+---+---+---+---+---+
```